# I'm trying to upload this script. But receiving: Error Message "SuiteScript version 2 file used for form scripts must implement client script type."

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suite

```
/\*\*

* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
  \*/

define(\['N/log', 'N/record'\],

    function(log, record) {
    
        function beforeSubmit(context) {
    
            try {
    
                // Get the new record from the context
    
                var newRecord = context.newRecord;
    
                // Check if the 'consoldaysoverdue' field has changed
    
                if (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT && newRecord.isFieldChanged({
    
                    fieldId: 'consoldaysoverdue'
    
                })) {
    
                    // Hide popup notifications for the 'consoldaysoverdue' field
    
                    newRecord.setField({
    
                        fieldId: 'suppressFieldRecalculation',
    
                        value: true
    
                    });
    
                }
    
            } catch (e) {
    
                // Log any errors
    
                log.error({
    
                    title: 'Error Hiding Popup Notification',
    
                    details: e.toString(),
    
                });
    
            }
    
        }
    
        return {
    
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
    
        };
    
    }

);
```

I've tried changing the script type to Client Script. And I get another error message that it must be a UserEvent Type. The function of this code is to eliminate the "Consolidated days due" pop up notification that keeps appearing on customer forms.

Comment: You might want to review the Netsuite help on this topic. There is no 'suppressFieldRecalculation' field nor a built-in isFieldChanged function. The client script API does specify a `fieldChanged` function that is called when the user changes the field but you must provide the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error you likely have to delete the script before you can upload a file with a changed script type. i.e. If you first uploaded your file with

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
```

and then defined a script you'd have to delete the script in order to change the script type defined in the file.

However given what you are trying to do a `ClientScript` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things to change in your code.

Besides the obvious change of `@NScriptType` to `UserEventScript` already suggested by @bknights, you need to implement the correct entry points. See NetSuite's [help page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4489981198.html#SuiteScript-2.x-Client-Script-Entry-Points-and-API) and look at the [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4410692508.html#fieldChanged(scriptContext)) `fieldChanged`. Note that the script context is completely different and oldRecord or newRecord do not exist there. You'll have to rewrite most of the script to adapt...

You also seem to be uploading the script file over an existing file that's already linked to the UE script. Try uploading with a new file name, or deleting the previous script record and source code file.

Finally, there seem to be some lingering backslashes (`\`) around your code pasted above, make sure they are not in the actual `.js` file.

Try this (untested)

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */

define([
    'N/log',
], (
    log,
) => {

    function fieldChanged(context) {
        try {
            if (context.fieldId === 'consoldaysoverdue') {
                // Hide popup notifications for the 'consoldaysoverdue' field
                context.currentRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'suppressFieldRecalculation',
                    value: true
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            log.error({
                title: 'Error Hiding Popup Notification',
                details: e.toString(),
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
    };

});
```